# Update date-frame with another data-frame which as a different number of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large `df` called `data` which looks like:

```
     Identifier     Surname  First names(s)  Date change  Work Pattern  Region 
0       12233.0       Smith             Bob                        FT      NW
1       54213.0       Jones           Sally     15/04/15           FT      NW
2       12237.0       Evans           Steve     26/08/14           FT      SE
3       10610.0      Cooper             Amy     16/08/12           FT      SE
```

I have another dataframe called `updates`.  In this example the dataframe has updated information for `data` for a couple of records and looks like:

```
     Identifier     Surname  First names(s)   Date change 
0       12233.0       Smith             Bob      05/09/14                  
1       10610.0      Cooper             Amy      16/08/12
```

I'm trying to find a way to update data with the updates df so the resulting dataframe looks like:

```
     Identifier     Surname  First names(s)  Date change  Work Pattern  Region 
0       12233.0       Smith             Bob     15/09/14           FT      NW
1       54213.0       Jones           Sally     15/04/15           FT      NW
2       12237.0       Evans           Steve     26/08/14           FT      SE
3       10610.0      Cooper             Amy     16/08/12           FT      SE
```

As you can see the Date change field for Bob in the `data` df has been updated with the `Date change` from the `updates` df.

What can I try next?

Comment: Take a look at `DataFrame.update`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html. You can use your `Identifier` column as the index, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a while back, I was dealing with that too. the straight up `.update` was giving me issues (sorry can't remember the exact issue I had. I think it was that when you do `.update`, it's reliant on indexes matching, and they didn't match in my 2 separate dataframes. so I wanted to use certain columns as my index to update on),

But I made a function to deal with it. So this might be way overkill than what's needed but try this and see if it'll work.

I'm also assuming the date you want update from the `updates` dataframe should be `15/09/14` not `05/09/14`. So I had that different in my sample data below

Also, I'm assuming the `Identifier` is unique key. If not, you'll need to include multiple columns as your unique key

```
import sys
import pandas as pd


data = pd.DataFrame([[12233.0,'Smith','Bob','','FT','NW'],
                    [54213.0,'Jones','Sally','15/04/15','FT','NW'],
                    [12237.0,'Evans','Steve','26/08/14','FT','SE'],
                    [10610.0,'Cooper','Amy','16/08/12','FT','SE']], 
                    columns = ['Identifier','Surname','First names(s)','Date change','Work Pattern','Region'])



updates = pd.DataFrame([[12233.0,'Smith','Bob','15/09/14'],
                    [10610.0,'Cooper','Amy','16/08/12']],
                    columns = ['Identifier','Surname','First names(s)','Date change'])




def update(df1, df2, keys_list):
    df1 = df1.set_index(keys_list)
    df2 = df2.set_index(keys_list)

    dup_idx1 = df1.index.get_duplicates()
    dup_idx2 = df2.index.get_duplicates()

    if len(dup_idx1) > 0 or len(dup_idx2) > 0:
        print('\n'+'#'*50+'\nError! Duplicate Indicies:')
        for element in dup_idx1:
            print('df1: %s' %(element,))
        for element in dup_idx2:
            print('df2: %s' %(element,))
        print('#'*50+'\n\n')

    df1.update(df2, overwrite=True)
    df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
    return df1


# the 3rd input is a list, in case you need multiple columns as your unique key
df = update(data, updates, ['Identifier'])
```

**Output:**

```
print (data)
   Identifier Surname First names(s) Date change Work Pattern Region
0     12233.0   Smith            Bob                       FT     NW
1     54213.0   Jones          Sally    15/04/15           FT     NW
2     12237.0   Evans          Steve    26/08/14           FT     SE
3     10610.0  Cooper            Amy    16/08/12           FT     SE


print (updates)
   Identifier Surname First names(s) Date change
0     12233.0   Smith            Bob    15/09/14
1     10610.0  Cooper            Amy    16/08/12
```

`df = update(data, updates, ['Identifier'])`

```
In [19]: print (df)
   Identifier Surname First names(s) Date change Work Pattern Region
0     12233.0   Smith            Bob    15/09/14           FT     NW
1     54213.0   Jones          Sally    15/04/15           FT     NW
2     12237.0   Evans          Steve    26/08/14           FT     SE
3     10610.0  Cooper            Amy    16/08/12           FT     SE
```

Comment: The built in `DataFrame.update` (`data.update(updates)`) works fine for the data you have in your example, given that you set index to `Identifier` on both `DataFrame`s so I don't really see why this code is useful...

Comment: ahhh. you know what, youre absolutely right. now I remember why I did this. I was doing this on multiple columns on multiple dataframes, 100's of times and was just tired of doing the `set_index`, then `reset_index`, etc. I just got annoyed when it wouldn't update for having duplicates in the index and needed a way to see exactly which duplicates were showing up, etc, etc, etc. So made this to just give me peace of mind. It was a long while ago, like I said. but yes, just set the index as 'Identifier' and then update is much simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using `DataFrame.update`.

First set index:

```
data.set_index('Identifier', inplace=True)
updates.set_index('Identifier', inplace=True)
```

Then update:

```
data.update(updates)

print(data)
           Surname First names(s) Date change Work Pattern Region
Identifier                                                       
12233.0      Smith            Bob    15/09/14           FT     NW
54213.0      Jones          Sally    15/04/15           FT     NW
12237.0      Evans          Steve    26/08/14           FT     SE
10610.0     Cooper            Amy    16/08/12           FT     SE
```

If you need multiple columns to create a unique `index` you can just set them with a list. For example:

```
data.set_index(['Identifier', 'Surname'], inplace=True)
updates.set_index(['Identifier', 'Surname'], inplace=True)

data.update(updates)
```